# Is there a convenient way to manually copy the Log Shipping *.trn files from one SQL 2008 server to another?

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-replication, log-shipping

We have a remote SQL 2008 server (ServerB) that needs to keep a warm (15 minute interval is OK) copy of production data (ServerA). ServerA is also SQL 2008. Log Shipping looks like it will do the job. We can only get to the destination ServerB with remote desktop. Is there a way to set this up when we can't get to both servers from one Management Studio? We want to be able to temporarily (until a VPN is setup between our network and the ServerB network) manually export a small .trn file, copy it via remote desktop to ServerB and then manually import those transactions from the .trn file. My supervisor says he saw a post saying this is possible. We were just trying to avoid doing a full database backup and copying that every time. Thanks in advance for any suggestions on this.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a little late but the easiest way I know to do this is to set up Log Shipping to generate the backup files. When you want to transfer the files start the Remote Desktop program, select options, Local Resources tab, Local Devices and Resources - more, select the local drive you want to map the other server.

Once you've connected to the other server the local drive will be visible and you can access and copy the backup files over. You may also need to manually apply these as you won't be able to configure the log shipping restore jobs on this server.